# unable to install sharp package using yarn

Tags: next.js, yarnpkg, package.json, sharp

when I run `yarn add sharp` I get the below call stack.
I tried manually installing semver with the below command with no luck either.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm yarn.lock
yarn add semver
yarn cache clean
yarn add sharp
```

```
b157181@ML-C02G68A0MD6R wholesale % yarn add sharp

yarn add v1.22.19
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
[1/5]   Validating package.json...
[2/5]   Resolving packages...
warning Resolution field "terser@5.14.2" is incompatible with requested version "terser@^5.16.8"
[3/5]   Fetching packages...
[4/5]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > engineering/catalog@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "axios@^1.4.0".
warning " > engineering/shopping-lists@1.9.1" has incorrect peer dependency "axios@^1.4.0".
warning " > @next/react-dev-overlay@12.3.4" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^17.0.2".
warning " > @next/react-dev-overlay@12.3.4" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^17.0.2".
warning " > styled-components@5.3.11" has unmet peer dependency "react-is@>= 16.8.0".
warning " > @testing-library/user-event@14.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
[5/5]   Building fresh packages...
[-/7] ⠈ waiting...
[2/7] ⠈ dtrace-provider
[7/7] ⠈ sharp
[-/7] ⠈ waiting...
error /Users/b157181/Desktop/Wholesale/wholesale/node_modules/sharp: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/b157181/Desktop/Wholesale/wholesale/node_modules/sharp
Output:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver/functions/coerce'
Require stack:
- /Users/b157181/Desktop/Wholesale/wholesale/node_modules/sharp/install/libvips.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/b157181/Desktop/Wholesale/wholesale/node_modules/sharp/install/libvips.js:14:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/b157181/Desktop/Wholesale/wholesale/node_modules/sharp/install/libvips.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.15.0
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver/functions/coerce'
Require stack:
- /Users/b157181/Desktop/Wholesale/wholesale/node_modules/sharp/lib/libvips.js
- /Users/b157181/Desktop/Wholesale/wholesale/node_modules/sharp/install/can-compile.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/b157181/Desktop/Wholesale/wholesale/node_modules/sharp/lib/libvips.js:10:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/b157181/Desktop/Wholesale/wholesale/node_modules/sharp/lib/libvips.js',
    '/Users/b157181/Desktop/Wholesale/wholesale/node_modules/sharp/install/can-compile.js'
  ]
```

relevant package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "13.4.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not get this error at version sharp@0.28.1 and below